# Resizing a rectangle in a canvas element using slider values

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, slider, drawrect

I want to be able to resize a rectangle on a canvas using a slider, while having these values display in two text boxes. I have this code working, but it keeps the old values visible on the canvas. I've tried using `clearRect()` before I call to `strokeRect()`, but that stopped my sliders from working.

In short, I want to draw a rectangle to the canvas, and have it so that two sliders resize it, one for width, and one for height. I'm relatively new to coding, so I know I've probably made an obvious mistake!

Here is my JS code for printing the values to the text boxes and drawing the rectangle:

```
$(function() {
   var c1=document.getElementById("c1");
   var ctx1=c2.getContext("2d");
   $( "#slider1" ).slider({
  value:100,
  min: 10,
  max: 500,
  step: 10,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#textBox1" ).val(ui.value + "cm");
    ctx1.strokeRect(0, 0,$( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ), $( "#slider2").slider( "value" ) );
  }
  });
  $( "#slider2" ).slider({
  value:100,
  min: 10,
  max: 500,
  step: 10,
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#textBox2" ).val(ui.value + "cm");
    ctx1.strokeRect(0, 0,$( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ), $( "#slider2").slider("value"));
  }
  });
$( "#textBox1" ).val($( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) + "cm");
$( "#textBox2" ).val($( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" ) + "cm");
 });
```

And my HTML code:

```
 <div id="slider1" class="slider"></div>
 <input type="text" id="textBox1" class="sizeBox" value="100cm">
 <label>Height</label></input>
 <br>
 <div id="slider2" class="slider"></div>
 <input type="text" id="textBox2" class="sizeBox" value="100cm">
 <label>Width</label></input>
 <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a couple of glitches in your code:**

- You're missing a closing quote on `"100cm"`.
- There is no `frameCanvas` element for `var c2=document.getElementById("frameCanvas")`

*There might be more glitches -- I stopped looking after finding those.*

**Alternatively**, you could listen for the `change` events on native `input-type=range` elements:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
ctx.lineWidth=3;

var width=75;
var height=60;

// listen to slider events
$rwidth=$('#rwidth');
$rwidth.attr({min:20,max:150}).val(width);
$rwidth.on('input change',function(){
    width=parseInt($(this).val());
    draw();
});
//
$rheight=$('#rheight');
$rheight.attr({min:20,max:150}).val(height);
$rheight.on('input change',function(){
    height=parseInt($(this).val());
    draw();
});

draw();

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,width,height);
    ctx.strokeRect(20,20,width,height);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Width:&nbsp<input id=rwidth type=range><br>
Height:&nbsp<input id=rheight type=range><br>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: yes I realised those typos too after I had asked the question. Your suggestions work too, and I have the values showing in my textboxes too. Thank you again :)